# NestJs + TypeORM + MySQL custom module giving error can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmCoreModule

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to create my own custom nestjs module using TypeOrm, but when I import this module in main AppModule its giving me error *'Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmCoreModule (TypeOrmModuleOptions, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.'*

But I import mysqlmodule in my RootModule then everything works fine.

what is wrong here?

```
@Global()
export class MySqlModule {
  public static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: MySqlModule,
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          name : 'CUSTOM_CONNECTION_NAME',
          type: 'mysql',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3306,
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password',
          database: 'database',
          logging: true,
       })
      ],
      providers: [
        MySqlService
      ],
      exports: [
        MySqlService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RootModule,
    MySqlModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: add `@Module({})` in your `MySqlModule` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!

After adding @Module worked for me, but now I am facing another issue. I am using custom name for mysql connection, and using that custom connection name while injecting repository and while registering entity but getting error "If CUSTOM_CONNECTION_NAMEConnection is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?"

Comment: follow https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases

Comment: I am following nestjs documentation but in my case I am having custom database module with custom connection name therefore the approach mentioned in nestjs documentation is not working for me

Comment: if you could show which part of your code is throwing that error, it will help us

Comment: Here is another module which registers entity 

`@Module({  
  imports: [ TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MyEntity])],  
  providers: [MyEntityService],  
  controllers: [MyEntityController],  
})  
export class MyEntityModule {}  `

Service injecting custom connection from MySqlModule

`@Injectable(). 
export class MyEntityService {. 
  private repository:Repository<MyEntity>;  

  constructor(. 
    @InjectConnection('CUSTOM_CONNECTION_NAME'). 
    private readonly connection: Connection,  
  ) {}
}
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237367/discussion-between-pravin-deore-and-micael-levi).

Comment: I think this happens because you didn't provide the connection name to `TypeOrmModule.forFeature`. Again: follow the docs :)

Comment: I provided connection name but still I am receiving same error.